# SAPI version for Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, speech, sapi

Is Microsoft updating SAPI or any speech components in Windows 8?

I can't seem to find any mention of any updated [APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh920511%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [technology](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh920512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to be included with Windows 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Windows 8 ships with the same SAPI 5.4 from Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

For windows 8 ui applications, there are no inbox speech apis.